# Packages different than file system paths in Java (and Android)

Tags: java, android

I am building an SDK in Java that has a public API and lots of internal 'private' classes. I would like to keep the public classes as public, but restrict the visibility of all the internals. I have to stick to Java 8, so I can't really take advantage of modularity introduced in later Java versions. We all know that in Java (unfortunately) packages are not really hierarchical - for example `com.test1.test2` package is not really a sub-package of `com.test1` and thus any class declared with `package` visibility modifier inside `com.test1.test2` will not be visible from class declared inside `com.test1`. I can't really simply put all the classes in a single directory as that would make working with the project a nightmare.

I was wondering if it's possible to keep the file system hierarchy as usual, but declare classes as if they were inside a single package. For example create 2 files like these:

1. `Class1` under path `com/test1/test2/Class1.java`

```
package com.test1;

class Class1 {}
```

2. `Class2` under path `com/test1/Class2.java`

```
package com.test1;

class Class2 {}
```

So that logically, both of these classes would end up under the same package and be accessible from within one another using `package` visibility modifiers.

I know this is highly unusual and probably not supported by many IDEs, but I gave it a try using plain old `javac` and as long as I specify each source file by it's full path it compiles and runs just fine. Do you see any technical problems with that, other than (obviously) breaking the 'good practices'. If it makes any difference it is an Android project but written in Java.

Comment: What you try will not work. As a workaround you could define a  final "key" class that only have a package-private constructor, place it in your common package where the classes reside that make use of the "private classes".  And make all the "private classes" to require in the constructor an instance of this key class (and check that in the constructor). Now the private classes can only be instantiated if you have access to the key class. However using reflection you can bypass this and everything else you invent to protect your private classes.

Comment: Not sure if it has changed, but to the best of my knowledge the mapping of the package "space" to directories is only a convention and convince.  At the end of the day it is your project, so breaking the conventions is your choice, I would suggest that you fully document the how and why you are eschewing the convention.  I suspect you may have to be careful with class name collisions.

Comment: Maybe modules are a way for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep two `.java` source files in separate directories, but having the Java classes belong to the same *package*, then you need multiple source root directories.

This is e.g. how test code is kept separate from regular code in a standard Maven project.

So, create the files as follows:

- `src1/com/test1/Class1.java`
- `src2/com/test1/Class2.java`

When compiling, have both `src1` and `src2` on the *source path*. Since the *source path* by default is the same as the *classpath*, that means using e.g. `javac -cp src1;src2 -d bin com/test1/Class1.java`, which will correctly find and compile `Class2` if it is used by `Class1`. All the compiled `.class` files are consolidated in the single destination directory (`bin` in this example).

Having multiple source roots is common (all Maven projects have them, by default), so it is fully supported by IDEs.